# What is the meaning of the hand gestures on Zetsubou Restaurant's cover?

Tags: sayonara-zetsubou-sensei

It's been a while since I watched this anime, and today I suddenly realized that the four ladies on the cover of Zetsubou Restaurant aren't all doing the heart hand gesture, but in fact have 4 different gestures:

[image: Zetsubou Restaurant cover]

The four characters are, in order:

- Abiru Kobushi
- Matoi Tsunetsuki
- Harumi Fujiyoshi
- Kiri Komori

Maybe it's been only an aesthetic choice, but given all the hidden messages in SZS, that's probably not the case.

Fujiyoshi's heart might signify romantic (yaoi?) love.
Tsunetsuki's hands instead seem to be in a Yoni Mudra pose, maybe symbolizing lust? (since she was the stalker in the series)

Are the other 2 gestures also some kind of Mudra (yoga gestures)?

Maybe Kobushi's doing an Hasta Mudra (apparently it's supposed to reduce anxiety)? I'm not sure what would be the relationship with her character.

And what about Komori? Is there some meaning behind this?

Comment: Looks to me like they are making a card suit. Spades, diamonds, hearts and clubs, in order from left to right.

Comment: @Dimitrimx maybe that should be an answer. I'm not sure if there's anything else to it (though I don't remember the context well).

Comment: @LoganM may be. I haven't seen/read the series, so I can't really tell if there's any message/meaning behind them making a card suit, beyond them making a card suit.

Comment: Yeah, when I noticed the card suits in the title, I also subsequently realized that's what their hands are representing. I wonder if there's still an hidden meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Club, diamond, heart, spade, the four suits on a pack of playing cards.

Comment: That's already been pointed out in the comments. The real question is whether there's any significance to them making those specific gestures?

Comment: Ah, I had Shut Up enabled! Thought no one had mentioned anything.